# Tagify mixed mode change format posted data

Tags: javascript, tagify

I use Tagify to add autocompletion in a textarea mixed with text and send the value to the server when the form is submitted and this works great.
But i would like to change the way the tags are included in the submitted data.

Tagify is smart enough to convert the textarea data into tags mixed with regular text:

```
<textarea name="test" type="text">Hello [[James]]! </textarea>
```

But when i submit the form is get

```
Hello [[{"value":"James"}]]!
```

I have made [an example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szntkq74/2/)

If i make a Tagify without *mode: 'mix'* and use the setting:

```
originalInputValueFormat: valuesArr => valuesArr.map(item => item.value).join(',')
```

then the output matches the input as expected.( **[[James]]** and not **[[{"value":"James"}]]** )

What must i do to get Tagify to change it's output?

Comment: Why does it matter to you if it works with `Hello [[{"value":"James"}]]` ?

Comment: Next version of Tagify will support the `originalInputValueFormat` setting for `mix`-mode

Answer (score 0):

The developer of Tagify solved [my problem](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify/issues/1037) by adding `originalInputValueFormat` for the mix mode. My [example](https://jsfiddle.net/tnwzsm4h/) now works as expected!

I only had to update Tagify to version 4.13.0 and add the following code to the constructor:

```
originalInputValueFormat: tagData => tagData.value,
```